# Alguém consegue me ajudar com esse erro de json em c#

Tags: c#

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Não é possível
>   desserializar a atual matriz JSON (por exemplo, [1,2,3]) no tipo'
>   Json.pulse 'porque o tipo requer um objeto JSON (por exemplo, {"name":
>   "value"}) para desserialize corretamente.

```
class Program
{
    int i1, i2, i3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string aux = @"https://api.monday.com:443/v1/boards/251379198/pulses.json?page=7&per_page=25&api_key=39eef5804de940f37d69b3d750c81212";
        var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp(aux);
        requisicaoWeb.Method = "GET";
        requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "RequisicaoWebDemo";
        var resposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse();
        var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
        object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pulse>``(objResponse.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(post);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class pulse
{
    public string id;
}
```

Comment: Cara, se poder, transcreve teu código para a pergunta

Comment: Pronto arrumei.

Answer (score 0):

Como o próprio erro aponta, você está tentando desserializar uma matriz para um objeto.

Use:  `var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(objResponse.ToString());`

Outra coisa é que sua classe `pulse` está diferente do retorno do `Json`. Sugiro usar o http://json2csharp.com/ para mapear o retorno do `Json` com sua classe `pulse`.

No mais isso deve funcionar para você.

```
class Program
{
        int i1, i2, i3;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string aux = @"https://api.monday.com:443/v1/boards/251379198/pulses.json?page=7&per_page=25&api_key=39eef5804de940f37d69b3d750c81212";
           var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp(aux);
           requisicaoWeb.Method = "GET";
           requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "RequisicaoWebDemo";
           var resposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse();
           var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
           object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
           var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(objResponse.ToString());
           foreach(var item in post)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(item.Pulse.id);
           }

           Console.ReadLine();
      }
}
public class Pulse
{
      public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
      public Pulse Pulse { get; set; }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]